# Can this frame be saved?

Tags: road-bike, frames, repair, cyclocross, aluminum

I had a little accident and went over the handlebars.

I'm okay, I was able to ride the bike home, but it is obviously bent. Everything else on the bike seems to be fine, the wheels are true and rides is straight still.

[image: Fuji Tread Gravel Bike]

Where can I take this to get it fixed?

Comment: The frame is done like dinner... sorry.

Comment: What's the frame made of?  I'm guessing aluminium based on the folds.   Was it a nice or expensive bike?   Unless you can find a local frame builder who does Aluminium work, its toast, and worth about $5 a kilo at the local scrap metal merchant.    Also, check your fork tines and steerer tube and bars super carefully - they tend to suffer damage too.   What you own now is a "parts donor"

Comment: Now given it was crash damage, you are unlikely to be covered by warranty,  However Fuji may be interested in the frame to diagnose why it failed so badly.  It could be worth contacting them.  http://www.advancedsports.com/support/warranty.php?brand=fuji

Comment: @Criggie: I wouldn't encourage OP to waste their time looking for someone to repair this frame.  It's impossible.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think its dead too - if OP wants to do an insurance claim then he's going to need better supporting documentation than some bunch of cyclenerds on SE.

Comment: The top dent is not that bad, and can be left alone if you keep an eye on it.  The bottom fold is a different matter.  A bailing-wire mechanic might get away with straightening it a bit (don't know how) and then splinting it with, eg, a piece of pipe sawn in half and clamped on with spiral hose clamps.  And some duct tape.

Comment: Out of interest, would you be able to append a description of how it happened?    I'm guessing that the front wheel dropped into a pothole or something at speed, and your momentum crumpled the bike until the back wheel came up and threw you over the bars.    BTW good effort for avoiding serious injury.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The frame is 100% trash.  Do not attempt to use it at all.

What you can do is to carefully remove everything from the frame.  Discard the frame, and now you have a whole bunch of valuable parts.  You can either buy a new (possibly second hand) frame, or just sell the parts to finance the purchase of another bike.

There are a few parts you won't be able to easily remove, such as the headset and the bottom bracket, but these are not very valuable anyway, so don't worry about buying the special tools for those.

Comment: Suggest "recycle" rather than discard the frame.

Comment: A bike store might be able to remove headset and bottom bracket and transfer them to a (fitting) new frame if they are worth salvaging.

Comment: @Carel Thats a good point. The bike is only 5 months old.

Comment: can you explain why this one should be discarded? I see posts of people fixing massive holes in their frames and people seem to applaud the effort. What's the problem here? (assuming OP has the garage/tools needed)

Comment: @marts That would be normal for steel frames.  This one is aluminium.  Test it for yourself with some scrap aluminium - first bend it with a vice/hammer, then straighten with the vice.  Then try rebending it in the same place, and you'll find it takes far less effort.   Also, welding aluminium requires a lot more skill and a special welder.  Finally, if it was repaired I'd be forever worrying about failure while riding - not conducive  to a relaxing or fast ride.